# How to found correct crash line in xcode during crash

Tags: iphone

Any one help to find out the correct crash line in xcode during crash .Its very difficult to debug .so help me as soon as possible.thanks in advance.

Regards,

Arunkumar.P

Answer (score 7):

You will need the .dSYM file generated during the build and the crash report. Inside your crash report find the memory addresses inside your App where the crash takes place. There should a line like

```
13  YourApp  0x0001910a 0x1000 + 98570
```

Where 0x0001910a is the crash memory address.

Then use the `atos` command on your command line to symbolicate the address. The syntax is like:

```
atos -arch arm -o [PATH]/YourApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/YourApp 0x0001910a
```

This will return the file, method and the line of the crash. Something like this:

```
-[YourView doSomething] (in YourApp) (YourView.m:474)
```

The atos command is part of XCode.

Answer (score -1):

Use break point in your code, and NSLog,
Build and debug you will see where is the crash line